# Beep() and/or windows error sounds won't play

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Beep() stopped working, as in like it won't actually play the sound. I can't hear anything. Also error messages when compiling in VS (or error messages in general) does not play a sound.

This started happening yesterday, and I haven't changed anything. Every other sound on the computer works.

Anyone knows how the hell I can fix this? The default sound device is my headset as per usual, and no sound device is muted etc.

Edit: Also, it does not matter if I switch default sound device to something else. Every other sound keeps playing, but Beep/error messages refuses to play.

Edit2: Heck, even other windows sounds are working, even "start as admin" sound works. I have absolutely no clue what this is.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is a programming question...

Comment: @Javia1492 I wasn't sure what to tag this under, so I tagged it under the tags where I have the problem. xd

Comment: Can you listen to Pandora?

Comment: @Crisfole Yes, music and all other stuff works fine. Just error messages (& beep()) that does not make a sound for whatever reason.

Comment: @Javia1492 `Beep()` is a programming construct so I think it qualifies.

Comment: @MarkRansom Possibly, but the question is too general and not detailed enough to qualify as a programming question. To say `Beep()` has stopped working is not enough (especially since it seems to be an assumption due to the and/or windows). If anything, its more of a debugging question?

Comment: See if this helps, it's about configuring Windows to turn *off* the beep: http://superuser.com/questions/10575/turning-off-the-cmd-window-beep-sound

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, but sadly that didn't work either. I'll keep looking! :/